# Flutter Drawer Widget - change Scaffold.body content

Tags: dart, flutter

When using the Flutter Scaffold.Drawer - is it possible to have the links in the Drawer change the content (Scaffold.body) on the page?

Similarly to having links in the navigation drawer change a Fragment in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply change the `state` of the content of your interest by interacting with your `Drawer` items like this:

[image]

Here is the relevant code for this example:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => new _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String text = "Initial Text";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(child: new DrawerHeader(child: new Container())),
              new Container (
                child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.info),
                          onTap:(){
                              setState((){
                                text = "info pressed";
                              });
                          }
                      ),
                      new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.save),
                          onTap:(){
                            setState((){
                              text = "save pressed";
                            });
                          }
                      ),
                      new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.settings),
                          onTap:(){
                            setState((){
                              text = "settings pressed";
                            });
                          }
                      ),

                    ]
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Test Page"),),
        body: new Center(child: new Text((text)),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just got started on flutter, exactly what I was looking for. All tutorials I found over the internet just create new widgets duplicating all the Scaffold that open-up as a new Activity. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to enhance this by calling `Navigator.of(context).pop();` inside each on `onTap` property to close the drawer automatically instead of manually

Comment: Cool thanks. I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this using a navigator?

Comment: Yes just use `Navigator.of(context).pop();` inside each `onTap` to close the drawer automatically.

Comment: That I understood, I mean the screen change, by adding  a navigator as the `body`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178292/discussion-between-jasxir-and-aziza).

Answer (score 9):

That's a very good solution from Aziza! Thank you. It works! I'd just want to add that it can also work for the whole body by replacing it with a widget state:

```
...
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String text = "Initial Text";
  Widget widgetForBody = SomeWidgetFromClass();
  ...
  ...
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(child: new DrawerHeader(child: new Container())),
          new Container (
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.info),
                      onTap:(){
                          setState((){
                            widgetForBody = AnotherWidgetFromClass();
                          });
                      }
                  ),
                  new ListTile(leading: new Icon(Icons.save),
                      onTap:(){
                        setState((){
                          widgetForBody = YetAnotherWidgetFromClass();
                        });
                      }
                  ),
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this for body of Scaffold:

```
        body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex));
```

and then in the main or state class do like so:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new MainFragment();
      case 1:
          return new CardMgmt();
}
}
}
```

CardMgmt and other classes in switch case have their own build method that will return a Widget and it will be place in body of your scaffold. Also they can be in the same dart file or even another file.
But I have another problem:
What to do if instead of drawer items, we have a button in another class like CardMgmt and we want it to return a Widget and update page?

Comment: I'm facing the same, did you find a solution?